# Does dynamodb require a fixed primary key value in queries?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have log-type data with no natural key. Amazon dynamodb requires a hash attribute in the table primary key, so I plan to use a uuid. The problem is it seems like I need to fix the hash value when querying but I of course want to query over all logs so can't specify a single uuid. Do I misunderstand this dynamodb query requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not misunderstand the requirement.

The only way to avoid a full table scan is by querying against a specific HashKey.

How do you want to query the data? Would it perhaps make sense to use a date(possible at hour resolution) as your hashkey and creating a local secondary index on UUID?

Comment: Simplifying.. attributes would be [latitude, longitude, description] and I'd want to query for all descriptions where a < latitude < b and c < longitude < d. Need to search across time, so I'm not sure of any key I could fix.

Comment: Hmm, yes in this case I'm not sure DynamoDB is the right tool for you. Have you looked at RDS?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to avoid relational db constraints for this case. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at ElasticSearch or AWS CloudSearch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize performance and throughput provisioning I would suggest finding a way to use the `Hash Key` in your query and then a Filter Expression to narrow the records according to your needs `(where a < latitude < b and c < longitude < d)`.

See [Specifying Conditions with Condition Expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) for more details.

If using a `Hash Key` in your query is not possible and you have to use `Scan` with a `Conditional Expression`, I would then suggest segmenting your tables by Date or Time following the suggested [Time Series Data Best Practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns) as you mentioned that you need to query the data across time:

> Instead of storing all items in a single table, you could use
>   multiple tables to store these items. For example, you could create
>   tables to store monthly or weekly data. For the table storing data
>   from the latest month or week, where data access rate is high, request
>   higher throughput and for tables storing older data, you could dial
>   down the throughput and save on resources.
>
> You can save on resources by storing "hot" items in one table with
>   higher throughput settings, and "cold" items in another table with
>   lower throughput settings. You can remove old items by simply deleting
>   the tables. You can optionally backup these tables to other storage
>   options such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). Deleting an
>   entire table is significantly more efficient than removing items
>   one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as you do
>   as many delete operations as put operations.